# IIS is losing or abandoning Custom Sessions

Tags: iis, application-pools

We have an aspx.net application with IIS 7.5 and we are facing a huge problem as this application is losing or abandoning sessions for no clear reason. Due to client restrictions we must use Custom Sessions instead IIS Sessions.

The Application Pool is using Pipeline : Integrated and Framework is 4 and all the ‘Recycling’ settings in the Application Pool has been set to FALSE.

The Customer Session I am talking about is a .cs class we created based on an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggested by Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to create custom Sessions. The only thing we did different from this Microsoft example is that we added another session variable
named ‘Token’ and every time we need to check for the session id.. we also check if the token exists. As you can see is a matter of simple validation.. but again, seems like IIS is discriminating this token session.

We used first global.asax to manage the begin_request, end_request, etc, etc .. and due to this problem we are using now handlers instead of global.asax but the issue is still occurring..

When we trace the application using Fiddler it reveals the token ID is empty however the session ID value still exists.. so I doesn’t make sense at all.

If it is someone who can give us an advice and tip or maybe has been on a similar issue and tell us what it was done to overcome the issue we really, really appreciate that help.

Please help

Hernan